# Ruby on rails route from controller to html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and facing a problem. Please see the screenshot at the bottom.

Ruby version: `ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]`

Rails version: `Rails 6.0.3.1`

Operating system: `Windows 10`

I have a **PagesController**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home       
  end
end
```

and a template `views/pages/home.html.erb`.

I have the route setup this way:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do      
     root 'pages#home'  
 end
```

Whenever I load the browser, the server hangs. I don't know what's the cause:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-06-02 21:15:50 +0530
   (2.8ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 306)
```

[image]

Comment: So what's your problem?  It looks good to me.  When you go to `root` of your app, you're loading the pages/home.html which is what you want, right?  What does the browser show?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn server stops when i load the page

Comment: @SteveTurczyn browser shows server cant be reached

Comment: What URL do you try to visit, what host and port your server has?

Comment: @Yakov localhost:3000

Comment: @Yakov please find the cmd screen shot above

Comment: @SteveTurczyn hi please find the screen shot above

Comment: I think this has something to do with windows not having SIGHUP or SIGHUSR signals. You should do a quick try on a linux based system, I would say use a free tier on AWS and use cloud 9 editor with a ubuntu image it has everything you need to run a rails app.

Comment: @pankajdoharey ok let me try

Comment: did you've checked the log level in development environment configs? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: @AndreDurao yes